# How do I export SAS text string to a Word document using DDE?

Tags: ms-word, sas, dde

I would like to export a string character from SAS to a word document (.docx) using Dynamic Data Exchange (DDE). Is this possible?

The SAS documentation on this is old and suggests I use the following commands:

```
filename testit dde 'winword|"file_path"!bookmark' notab;

data _null_;
  file testit;
  put 'insertstuff';
run;
```

SAS returns an error message:

ERROR: Physical file does not exist

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Are you having a specific problem?  Googling SAS DDE WORD returns plenty of hits. If you want to read user papers, I would look for those by Koen Vyverman.

Comment: Well the code doesn't work! I have a Word document with lots of table and numbers and I would like a way to automate the input of those numbers. My supervisor is using ODS layouts to produce the entire document in SAS. In my opinion, this is not the best way to go about the problem. It would be better to link the numbers with a SAS program using the above code provided. However, I believe the code is outdated. SAS returns an error message. Something about SAS not understanding the file path specified. Can you try using the code yourself to see if you can get it to work? Thank you!

Comment: I actually agree with your boss. The only issue with that methodology is that you need strong SAS programmers to maintain your system. Have you created the bookmark in your Word file?

Comment: Yes, I have created a bookmark.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me.

```
filename testit dde 'winword|"e:\blah.docx"!bookmark' notab;

data null;
  file testit;
  put 'insertstuff';
run;
```

Steps:

1. Create a word document and save it in the specified path.
2. In word document, create a bookmark by going to Insert->Bookmark, give it a name of 'Bookmark' and press Add
3. Make sure both word and SAS are open.  And that the document is open in word.
4. Run the SAS code.

Comment: BTW - I also don't endorse the use of DDE if it can be avoided.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you don't recommend using DDE? If the code works, then it seems like a good solution to the problem...

Comment: DDE won't work on SAS server. It's old deprecated technology. Microsoft could drop it any time. For word, I liked this paper on making an RTF file with your document, then editing that with a data _null_ step. http://www.wuss.org/proceedings11/Papers_Carpenter_A_74920.pdf

Comment: Hmm. I think we're using SAS server. So I guess I'll have to create an RTF file in SAS, which I was hoping to avoid...

Answer (score 0):

Super late to the party, but there are a few issues that could cause that error:

1. You don't need `""` around the filename, should just be:

   ```
   filename testit dde 'winword|file_path!bookmark' notab;

   data _null_;
     file testit;
     put '[Insert "stuff"]';
   run;
   ```
2. The file path may be spelled incorrectly
3. You may not have permissions to the filepath. This is likely if it is a work machine. 
   To check:

   1. Navigate to the filepath in the file explorer
   2. Right click on the file
   3. Open properties
   4. Look for your username, click on it, and it will show you what permission you have
4. You have a missing/incorrect file extension (ie `.doc` not `.docx` ect)

Hope you were able to figure this out at the time :P